# Check/observe what is currently being played by the Android system

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I'm looking for a solution to observe what the app is currently playing. At minimum I would need to know what URI is being used to play Media and what is current playback position.

We are giving developers API with media content (MP3/HLS files) and to give them the best experience we are asking them to send various events to our API. Based on those events we can prepare better content for their users. We would like to ease the process of tracking events by implementing library that will be responsible for tracking those events. To do it we need to observe/query what their app is currently playing and what is a playback position. That's why I'm looking for a solution that will let me do this without caring too much what kind of player app is using (MediaPlayer, ExoPlayer or any other solution).

Is there any tool that will let me check those informations?

Comment: Your app should already know what they are playing ...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that we are building it as a library. So we have an API that developers can consume - get personalized media content. To give them a better media content we need to track a few events. Forcing every developer to track those events seems like a bad plan. That is why we would like to give them a library that will do it for them. To detect those events we just need to know what is currently playing and playback position